# Git rebase to rearrange commits involving same file

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have one file, say `foo.txt`. I add one line to it, so that it now looks like:

```
*existing content*
Line 1
```

I commit it with the message "First change". Now I open the same file again, and add another line at the end, so that it now looks like:

```
*existing content*
Line 1
Line 2
```

This I commit with the message "Second change". `git log` shows "Second change" as the topmost change, followed by "First change", as expected. Now I want to reverse the two commits, so that "First cange" comes at the top, and the "Second change" comes second from top.

I tried doing it with `git rebase -i`, I am getting consecutive merge conflicts, which I am resolving. But after that, I am left with only one commit, "Second change", the "First change" commit, which I want at the top, is now lost.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to show more of your process.

I created a small repository and a file `foo.txt`, added those two lines in two commits, and ran `git rebase -i` and swapped them:

```
pick f196c5b second change
pick 8d6ad6a first change
```

resulting in:<sup>1</sup>

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
existing content
<<<<<<< HEAD
||||||| parent of f196c5b... second change
Line 1
=======
Line 1
Line 2
>>>>>>> f196c5b... second change
```

which I now must resolve manually.  What should I choose as the result?  I think it is this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
existing content
Line 2
```

so I edit the file to have that and exit the editor, `git add foo.txt`, and run `git rebase --continue`;<sup>2</sup> and I get another conflict, resulting in:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
existing content
<<<<<<< HEAD
Line 2
||||||| parent of 8d6ad6a... first change
=======
Line 1
>>>>>>> 8d6ad6a... first change
```

How should I resolve this?  I think the answer is to keep `Line 2` from `HEAD` while also keeping `Line 1` from `8d6ad6a... first change`.  It's up to me what order to put these lines into, but I think I will use:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
existing content
Line 2
Line 1
```

so I write that to the file, exit the editor, `git add foo.txt`, and `git rebase --continue`.

That finishes the rebase and the file is now in the form it had in my last conflict-resolution.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `|||||||` through `=======` section appears because I have `merge.conflictStyle` set to `diff3`.  This shows me what is in the common ancestor.  It's most useful during real merges—the "merge base" of a cherry-pick is a bit suspect—but I like to keep it on at all times.

<sup>2</sup>I omit the editor sessions for writing new commit messages for the new copies of the old commits, since they are not relevant to the final result.  (Remember, `git rebase` is *copying* commits.  Once the rebase is done, `ORIG_HEAD` remembers the original, pre-rebase-copying, commits; the current branch name now finds the new, post-copy commits.)